# Bootsrap not loading when deployed but working when in localhost

Tags: php, jquery, sql, bootstrap-4

Its not working like just blank screen but when it's in localhost it works just fine i also looked how to check error using firefox dev tools and it just says 500 Internal Server Error

the site is http://mabatanghealth.lovestoblog.com/scheduling.php

it should display a calendar of some sort..
Thank you guys.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/indexdesign011.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/all.min.css">
        
         <style>
            @media only screen and(max-width: 760px),
            (min-device-width:802px) and(max-device-width:1020px){
table,
thead,
tbody,
th,
td,
tr{
    display:block;
}
.empty{
    display:none;
}
th{
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    left:-9999px;
}
tr{
    border:1px solid #ccc;

}
td{
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:50%;
}

td:nth-of-type(1):before{
    content:"Sunday";
}td:nth-of-type(2):before{
    content:"Monday";
}td:nth-of-type(3):before{
    content:"Tuesday";
}
td:nth-of-type(4):before{
    content:"Wednesday";
}td:nth-of-type(5):before{
    content:"Thursday";
}
td:nth-of-type(6):before{
    content:"Friday";
}
td:nth-of-type(7):before{
    content:"Saturday";
}
            }   

 @media only screen and (min-device-width:802px) and(max-device-width:1020px){
     body{
         width:495px;
     }}
     @media(min-width:641px){
         table{
             table-layout:fixed;
         }

         td{
             width:33%;
         }
     }

 .row{
     margin-top:20px;
 }         
.today{
    background:yellow;
}

             </style>
</head>       

    <body>
 

<div class="container01">
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class= "logo">
                  <ul>
                <li>Mabatang</li>
                <ul>
                </div>
               
                <div class= "logo2">
                  <ul>
                <li> </li>
                <li>|Health </li>
                <ul>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="HOME.php">Home</a></i></li>
                        <li><a href="Quiz.php">Quiz</a></i></li>
                        <li><a href="scheduling.php">Schedule</a></i></li>
                   
                        </ul>
                </nav>


                <div class="user">
    <?php Session_START();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_email'])) {

    $session_name=$_SESSION['user_email'];
  
    if($session_name=="admin@gmail.com"){
   
      echo $_SESSION['user_email'];
      echo '<a href="Report.php?namevar=name&strandvar=strand&gradevar=grade"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></a>
      </a></li>';
     
     
      echo '<a href="scheduling.php"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></a>
      </a></li>';
    
      echo '<a href="studlist.php"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></a>
    </a></li>';
    
    
    
    echo ' <a href="changeuser.php?user_email=<?php echo $result[$k]["user_email"]>
     
     </a></li>';
    
    echo '   <a href="logout.php">
    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
    </a></li>';
    
    
     
    }
    
    
    
    
    if($session_name=="grades@gmail.com"){
    
    
      echo $_SESSION['user_email'];
      echo '<a href="grade11_sems.php"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a>
      </a></li>';
    
    
    echo '<a href="studlist.php"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></a>
    </a></li>';
    
    
    echo ' <a href="changeuser.php?user_email=<?php echo $result[$k]["user_email"]>
     
    
     </a></li>';
    echo '   <a href="logout.php">
    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
    </a></li>';
    }
    
    
    
    if( ($session_name != "admin@gmail.com")&&($session_name != "grades@gmail.com")){
      $session_name=$_SESSION['user_email'];
      echo $_SESSION['user_email'];
      
      echo '<a href="scheduling.php"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></a>';
    echo '<a href="changeuser.php?user_email=<?php echo $result[$k]["user_email"]></a> ';
    
    
    echo "<a href='studgrades11.php?emailvar=$session_name'>11</a>";
    echo "<a href='studgrades12.php?emailvar=$session_name'>12</a>";
    echo '  <a href="logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>';
    }} 
      else{
        echo'<a href="login.php">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i></a> </a></li>';
    }
    
  ?>  
      </ul>
                </nav></div></div>
  </div></div>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php
            $dateComponents=getDate();
            if(isset($_GET['month']) && isset($_GET['year'])){

                $month = $_GET['month'];                 
                
                $year = $_GET['year'];
                
                 }else{
                
                $month = $dateComponents['mon'];                 
                
                $year = $dateComponents['year'];
                
                }
            echo build_calendar($month,$year);
            
            ?>
<?php
function build_calendar($month,$year){
$mysqli = new mysqli ("127.0.0.1", "root","user","guidance");
// $stmt=$mysqli->prepare('select * from user_info where MONTH(date)= ? AND YEAR(date)= ?');
//  $stmt->bind_param('ss',$month,$year);
//  $bookings=array();
//  if($stmt->execute()){
//     $result=$stmt->get_result();
//      if($result->num_rows > 0){
//          while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
//             $bookings[]=$row['date'];
//          }
//         $stmt->close();
//     }

//  }







    //name of days
    $daysOfWeek=array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    //first day of month
    $firstDayOfMonth=mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
    //number of days in a month
    $numberDays=date("t",$firstDayOfMonth);
    //info on 1st day of month
    $dateComponents=getdate($firstDayOfMonth);
    //getting name of this month
    $monthName =$dateComponents['month'];
    //index value of the 1st day
    $dayOfWeek=$dateComponents['wday'];   
    //currentdate
    $dateToday=date('Y-m-d');

$prev_month=date('m',mktime(0,0,0,$month-1,1,$year));
$prev_year=date('Y',mktime(0,0,0,$month-1,1,$year));
$next_month=date('m',mktime(0,0,0,$month+1,1,$year));
$next_year=date('Y',mktime(0,0,0,$month+1,1,$year));
$calendar="<center><h2>$monthName $year</h2>";
 
    $calendar.="<a class= 'btn btn-xs btn-primary' href='?month=".$prev_month."&year=".$prev_year."'>Previous Month</a>";
    $calendar.="<a class= 'btn btn-xs btn-primary' href='?month=".date('m')."&year=".date('Y')."'>Current Month</a>";
    $calendar.="<a class= 'btn btn-xs btn-primary' href='?month=".$next_month."&year=".$next_year."'>Next Month</a> <center>";
    $calendar.="<table class='table table-bordered'>";
    $calendar.="<tr>";
    foreach($daysOfWeek as $day){
        $calendar.="<th class='header'>$day</th>";   
    }
    
$calendar.="</tr><tr>";
$currentDay=1;
if($dayOfWeek>0){
    for($k=0;$k<$dayOfWeek;$k++){
        $calendar.="<td class='empty'></td>";


    }
}
$month=str_pad($month,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
while($currentDay<=$numberDays){
    if($dayOfWeek==7){
        $dayOfWeek=0;
        $calendar.="</tr><tr>";
    }
    $currentDayRel=str_pad($currentDay,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $date="$year-$month-$currentDayRel";
    $dayName=strtolower(date('l',strtotime($date)));
    $today=$date==date('Y-m-d') ? 'today': '';

  if($dayName =='saturday' || $dayName =='sunday'){
        $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4><a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>No Classes</td>";
        
    }
    elseif($date<date('Y-m-d')){
        $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4><a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>N/A</td>";       
    }

    else{ 
        
        $totalbookings=checkSlots($mysqli,$date);
        if($totalbookings==8){
            $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4><a href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Fully Booked</td>";
        }else{
$availableslots=8-$totalbookings;   
 $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4><a href='book.php?date=".$date."' 
 class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Book</a> <small><i>$availableslots Slots Left</i></small>";}

    }
    $currentDay++;
    $dayOfWeek++;
}

if($dayOfWeek<7){
    $remainingDays = 7 - $dayOfWeek;
    for($i=0;$i<$remainingDays;$i++){
        $calendar.="<td clas s='empty'></td>";
    }
}

$calendar.="</tr></table>";

    return $calendar;   
     


}

function checkSlots($mysqli,$date){
 $stmt=$mysqli->prepare('select * from user_info where date = ?');
  $stmt->bind_param('s',$date);
  $totalbookings=0;
  if($stmt->execute()){
    $result=$stmt->get_result();
      if($result->num_rows > 0){
         while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
             $totalbookings++;
         }
         $stmt->close();
     }

  }
   return $totalbookings; 
}




?>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them) See in particular the section about "White screen of death" which will help you learn how to find the details behind that "error 500".

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this...

```
<?php Session_START();
```

to this...

```
<?php session_start();
```

But it really should be at the top of your script before you output any HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately it still not working it the error is still there GET 500 internal server error.